# Product of Gaussian densities, why don't the formulas apply to this case?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, gaussian

I was reading the paper 'A Bayesian tutorial for data assimilation'  from Wikle and Berliner and there is this paragraph.

[image]

I don't understand how they get to the distribution from X|y. I expected the distribution to be $X|y \sim  N\Big( (\frac{1}{\sigma^2} +\frac{1}{\tau ^2})^{-1}(\frac{x}{\sigma^2} +\frac{\mu}{\tau^2}) , (\frac{1}{\sigma^2} +\frac{1}{\tau^2})^2\Big)$,

because that is what you get when you fill in the formula for the product of gaussian densities.

$\mathcal{N}_x(\mu_1 , \Sigma_1)\mathcal{N}_x(\mu_2 , \Sigma_2) = \mathcal{N}_x(\mu_3 , \Sigma_3)$

With

$ \mu_3 = (\Sigma_1^{-1} + \Sigma_2^{-1})^{-1} (\Sigma_1^{-1}\mu_1 +\Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2)$

$\Sigma_3 = (\Sigma_1^{-1} +\Sigma_2^{-1})^{-1}$

I used $\Sigma_1 = \sigma^2$ , $\Sigma_2 = \tau^2$ , $\mu_1 = x$ and $\mu_2= \mu$. I got these values from $X \sim N(\mu, \tau^2)$ and $Y_i |X = x \sim N(x ,\sigma)^2$.

Could someone explain why these formulas don't work for this case?

( I also tried completing the square, as they say in the paper, but then I also don't get their results)

Comment: Can you refer what are the mean and covariance of the two Gaussians you are multiplying (what are $\mu_1,\mu_2, \Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ for you). I say this because in the result, there should clearly be a factor of $n$ somewhere due to the presence of the $n$ original Gaussian densities coming from the samples. However, there is no $n$ in your result. Also, what is the $x$ in the mean parameter of your result (where you write $(x/\sigma^2 + \mu/\tau^2)$)? $x$ is the variable of the density, and cannot be a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the complete the square part. You have:
$$
x^2(n/\sigma^2+1/\tau^2) - 2\left(\sum y_i/\sigma^2+\mu/\tau^2\right)x = ax^2-2bx
$$
by defining:
$$
a = (n/\sigma^2+1/\tau^2),\ \ \ \  b=\left(\sum y_i/\sigma^2+\mu/\tau^2\right)
$$

Now, recall the completing the square trick says that:
$$
a(x-b/a)^2-b^2/a = ax^2-2bx+b^2/a-b^2/2 = ax^2-2bx
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\exp\left(-0.5\left[x^2(n/\sigma^2+1/\tau^2) - 2\left(\sum y_i/\sigma^2+\mu/\tau^2\right)x\right]\right)\\
& = \exp\left(-0.5\left[ax^2+bx\right]\right)\\
&= \exp\left(-0.5\left[a(x-b/a)^2-b^2/a\right]\right)\\
&=\exp\left(-0.5\left[a(x-b/a)^2\right]\right)\exp\left(0.5b^2/a\right)\\
&\propto \exp\left(-0.5\left[a(x-b/a)^2\right]\right) \\
&= exp\left(-\frac{(x-b/a)^2}{2a^{-1}}\right)\\
&= exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu')^2}{2{\sigma'}^2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
with
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mu' &= b/a = (n/\sigma^2+1/\tau^2)^{-1}\left(\sum y_i/\sigma^2+\mu/\tau^2\right)\\
{\sigma'}^2 &= a^{-1} = (n/\sigma^2+1/\tau^2)^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

I don't know where your procedure might have gone wrong, since I don't understand which two Gaussian densities you were multiplying, but your result is clearly wrong: a factor of $n$ should appear somewhere due to the presence of the original $n$ Gaussian densities coming from the $n$ samples. Moreover, $x$ cannot appear as a parameter of the Gaussian density as in your result.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you :) yes, for the completing the square it helps. But I'm still confused about the formulas. I thought you had to multiply $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu , \tau^2)$ and $Y_i|X \sim \mathcal{N}(x , \sigma^2)$. Is it because the second one is for $Y_i|X$ and not $Y|X$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that is the issue. You would have to multiply the $n$ gaussian densities first (as in the paper) or apply your formula $n$ times and not only once.